# 'coqc' does not find findlib.conf

Tags: homebrew, coq

```
~ % coqc
Error:
Anomaly
"Uncaught exception Failure("Config file not found - neither /usr/local/etc/findlib.conf nor the directory /usr/local/etc/findlib.conf.d")."
Please report at http://coq.inria.fr/bugs/.
```

I was trying to use Spacemacs and the coq layer but 'coqc' itself throws an
error.

What could be wrong ?

I installed coq using home-brew.

```
==> Installing dependencies for coq: ocaml and ocaml-zarith
==> Installing coq dependency: ocaml
==> Pouring ocaml--4.14.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz   /usr/local/Cellar/ocaml/4.14.0: 2,425 files, 396.8MB
==> Installing coq dependency: ocaml-zarith
==> Pouring ocaml-zarith--1.12_2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz   /usr/local/Cellar/ocaml-zarith/1.12_2: 38 files, 831.8KB
==> Installing coq
==> Pouring coq--8.16.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz   /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.16.1: 5,474 files, 662.8MB
==> Running `brew cleanup coq`...
```

Comment: seems an ocaml problem. Can you do a 
`ocamlfind printconf` to see what is the output

Comment: I think it is solved.`brew install ocaml-findlib` and then `ocamlfind printconf` shows meaningful env. values.`coqc` works.

Comment: Can you mark the question as solved, by adding your own answer?

Comment: I created https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/126774 since this is a clear dependency issue in homebrew caused by changes in Coq 8.16.

Comment: The dependencies should be fixed in Homebrew now (see above issue).

Comment: I still have the issue on GiitPod (Linuxbrew)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `brew install ocaml-findlib` and then `ocamlfind printconf` shows meaningful env. values.

`coqc` works after this.

And as mentioned in the comments the [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/126774) is addressed.